# The right Jenkins job copyArtifact Permission syntax in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I've searched and found many topics about adding copyArtifact permission to jenkins project programmatically, but I'm not able to get working with my groovy pipeline generator code.

Here is the block code where I'm generating my multipipeline job, trying to set `copyArtifact` permission at the same time.

```
 24       multibranchPipelineJob("my_project") {
 25         branchSources {
 26           branchSource {
 27             source {
 28               git {
 29                 remote("my_repo")
 30                 credentialsId(${credential_id})
 31                 traits {
 32                   gitBranchDiscovery()
 33                   cleanBeforeCheckoutTrait {
 34                     extension {
 35                       deleteUntrackedNestedRepositories(false)
 36                     }
 37                   }
 38                 }
 39               }
 40             }
 41             strategy {
 42               defaultBranchPropertyStrategy {
 43                 props {
 44                 }
 45               }
 46             }
 47           }
 48         }
 49         properties {
 50           copyArtifactPermissionProperty {
 51             projectNameList('*')
 52           }
 53         }
 54         triggers {
 55           periodic(5)
 56         }
 57         orphanedItemStrategy {
 58           discardOldItems {
 59             // numToKeep(20)
 60           }
 61         }
 62         if ("jenkinsfile") {
 63           factory {
 64             workflowBranchProjectFactory {
 65               scriptPath("jenkinsfile")
 66             }
 67           }
 68         }
 69       }
```

Jenkins keeps raising the error bellow :

> ERROR: (pipeline_gen.groovy, line 50) No signature of method:
> javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.properties.FolderPropertiesContext.copyArtifactPermissionProperty()
> is applicable for argument types:
> (structure$_run_closure1$_closure5$_closure7$_closure8$_closure10$_closure23)
> values:
> [structure$_run_closure1$_closure5$_closure7$_closure8$_closure10$_closure23@27252a3] > > Finished: FAILURE

The message says the the signature at line `50` is not good.

I've tried the following syntaxes :

this ==>

```
 49         properties {
 50           copyArtifactPermissionProperty {
 51             projectNames('*')
 52           }
 53         }
```

this ==>

```
 49        options {
 50             copyArtifactPermission('*')
 51         }
```

this ==>

```
 49         properties {
 50           copyArtifactPermission('*')
 51         }
```

this ==>

```
 49         properties ([
 50           copyArtifactPermission('*'),
 51         ])
```

But none up there works.

What the right groovy syntax to achieve this please?

Comment: There is no such configuration option for the `multibranchPipelineJob`, it is also not available when you create such a job via the UI, you can check `<JENKINS_URL>/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html` to see all available options.

Comment: Ok @NoamHelmer, thx.

How if I want to automatically set the permission wen each job branch is add  to the above **multibranchPipelineJob**? I mean every time a new branch is created on the the associated repository, a corresponding pipeline job is added into the parent **multibranchPipelineJob**. How to set **cypyArtifact** permission  to each new created branch pipeline job programmatically?

Comment: The multibranchPipelineJob will just create the relevant jobs for each branch - these job are just calling the `Jenkinsfile` inside each branch, and this file contains the actual execution logic and inside it you can include the copy artifact permissions configuration using the `copyArtifactPermission` keyword. [Read More Here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/)